# Retrieve $BITMAP cluster/block no. from MFT

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap, block, ntfs-mft

Does anyone know how to get the cluster/block no. of $BITMAP file from MFT in C/C++?
I know the file record number of $BITMAP file in MFT is 6, but how can I know its sector or block/cluster no.?
Actually I want to read the $Bitmap file.

Note: I don't want to use Windows API.

Awaiting a positive response.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uh ... if you don't want to use the Windows API, what do you want to use?

Comment: I want to write a code that is cross platform. Basically I have a database and I need to read the $BITMAP file from it. I have parsed MFT by reading boot sector, but now I want to know the block/cluster no. of $BITMAP file to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by parsing the MFT. I have referred this post from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81456/An-NTFS-Parser-Lib?fid=1572260&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=1#xx0xx). I have read/parsed MFT_IDX_BITMAP file and then read the $DATA attribute.